# Implementing COMET clientside

Tags: javascript, streaming, comet

I have read up about what COMET streaming is, and all the various hacks required to get it working across the major browsers. The problems encountered seem to be two fold: 1. Server being able to support many persistent connections 2. Implementing the JS functionality

I have an application where I need to perform COMET streaming. I have already tackled the first problem above - I have a custom server running which delivers updates as it arrives in chunks. I want to now be able to connect using JS to this URL, so I can receive the updates.

Is there a simple COMET library I can use for this? I saw the Orbited project. Can I use the client side JS of orbited to perform this? What kind of modifications do I need to perform in the backend for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can get your server code to conform to the Bayeux specification then you can use any of the existing [cometd javascript implementations](http://cometdproject.dojotoolkit.org/documentation/cometd-javascript), current available in DOJO and jQuery. Unfortunately, the spec is quite complex, especially if you want to do both long-polling and callback-polling. You may be better of just running an existing cometd server like Jetty and then writing a client library for your server code to push data to it.

Comment: There is a BayreuxClient implementation in the java client sample code in the Cometd distribution which handle all the details providing a simple interface including call back for incoming messages.